# 3 Column Site Columns Floated Left But Not Appearing in Correct Order

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working on a 3 column site which I am converting to a RWD and which was previously laid out with nasty neg px margins but I am converting all this to percentages and em's so that the site will best suit a wide range of devices.

My problem is very similar to the post that can be seen here;
[HTML float right element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287265/html-float-right-element-order)

I have tried what was suggested in this article by @bookcassey by placing all the columns in a container which is floated right with all the child elements inside floated left but even doing this I still can't get the columns in order of #NavColumn #ContentColumn #ExtraColumn.

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>3 Col Page</title>

<meta name='description' content='Sample 3 Column Page'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="./support-files/landscapemobile.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="PageWrapper">
    <div id="Header">
    <div class="Liner">

    Header Links Etc

    </div> <!-- End Header Liner -->
    </div> <!-- End Header -->

    <!-- Begin Center Column Content -->
    <div class="OuterBG threecol"> <!-- disregard. There are no rules for this. This was part of a tut-->
    <div class="MidBG"> <!-- disregard. There are no rules for this. This was part of a tut-->
    <div class="InnerBG">
    <div id="ContentColumn"> <!-- col1 in tut -->
    <div class="Liner">

<h1>Page Headline</h1>

Page Content, Images Lorem Upsim etc...

</div> <!-- End Content Column -->
</div> <!-- End Liner -->

<div id='NavColumn'>
<div class='Liner'>
<div class='Navigation'>
Site 
Navigation
Links
</div><!-- end Navigation -->        
</div><!-- end Navigation Liner -->
</div><!-- end NavColumn -->

<div id='ExtraColumn'>
<div class='Liner'>
Extra
Column 
Content
</div><!-- END Extra Column Liner-->
</div><!-- END ExtraColumn -->


</div><!-- END colleft -->
</div><!-- END colmid -->
</div><!-- END colmask and threecol -->
<div id='Footer'>
Footer Content, Address etc...
</div>
</div><!-- END PageWrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
#PageWrapper{ 
    margin:1em auto;
    max-width:60em; /*960px / Default Font Size of 16px = em result*/
    border:0.3125em groove #DDDDDD;
    background-image:url(../image-files/background.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

.InnerBG{float:right;/*border:3px solid red;*/width:100%;}

#Header{position:relative;}

#Header .Liner{padding:0;}

#Header a.header-home-link{max-width:60em;display:block;}

#Header img{display:block;}

#ShareThis{width:100%;margin:1em auto 2em;}

#NavColumn, #ContentColumn, #ExtraColumn {float:left;}

#ContentColumn{max-width:62.50%;/*border:2px solid green;*/width:100%;}

#NavColumn{max-width:18.645833333%;text-align:center;font-size:90%;color:#000;width:100%;}

#ExtraColumn{max-width:18.645833333%;text-align:center;font-size:90%;color:#000;width:100%;}
```

Side Note: The colored columns were something I was trying to "See" each column

I've been through an untold number of tutorials and have been working on this for longer than I care to admit while trying every possible combination of CSS rules to no avail and if anyone knows how I could remedy the way the columns are displaying as can be seen here: http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/, I'd be MOST appreciative and I thank each and everyone of you in advance.

Comment: So you want the second div to the left, the first div in the middle and the last div to the right. Hm.

Comment: by what order you need columns can you name 1,2,3 so that it may be easy to understand for me...

Comment: Also, your "END" comments don't all match the corresponding divs.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about the delay in my response, I was away for a few minutes. @MrLister I'm wanting the column with the heading of "Share This" to be in the far left column, the main content in the middle and the right column pretty much just like it is displaying

Comment: Hi @AamirShahzad-aash1010 Thank you for taking a look. Please see my response above directed to Mr Lister. Thanks

Comment: @MrLister I know what you're talking about in reference to the END comments. This is remanents from an earlier tutorial, however the comments shouldn't have any effect should they? I was just leaving some of the xtra stuff from tutorials etc in place until I get the real problem sorted, then I can backtrack, removing the excess

Comment: There is no "Share this" column.

Comment: I'm sorry @MrLister for the misunderstanding. I meant I would like for #NavColumn (which houses an h2 "Share This") to be in the far left column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do more or less what you were asking (except for your "Share This" column, which wasn't there) by putting the first two columns in the `MidBG` div, which I floated left. Then I floated the first column right, so that the second one ended up before the first one, and the third one ended up to the right.
I also had to remove lots of `width:100%`s, which messed things up.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kc9SE/2/).

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but it is what you asked for...

Comment: You are amazing!! I tried up voting your answer but was unable due to my low score. I Thank you immensely for showing me how to correct this. Now lemme work on implementing it and I'll let you know how it turns out. If you don't mind, Could you take another look and offer any advice on using one less div than the way you did it? I'd like to clean it all up to look very similar to the code that can be seen on any of my main pages. Ie; (Albeit fixed. very clean code http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/about.html)

Comment: Hi again @MrLister I've been working on this while also removing excess code but I'm also still having trouble. You say you placed the first two columns in MidBG (Which I renamed to OuterWrapper) and floated this left but looking at the css I see nothing for MidBG

Comment: Sorry, `InnerBG`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very sloppy and disorganized and you have a lot of extraneous stuff going on in there, but since you didn't write much I think it's best you start over.

I wrote out a basic three column layout that can get you started with what you want to do. I also allowed it to be fluid(RWD) as you wanted.

Keep this same concept in mind when building your site and you should be fine.

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="col1">
</div>
<div id="col2">
</div>
<div id="col3">
</div>
</div<!--end wrap-->
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
width:100%;
}

#col1{
background-color:blue;
width:33.33%;
height:200px;
float:left;
}
#col2{
background-color:red;
width:33.33%;
height:200px;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
#col3{
background-color:green;
float:right;
width:33.33%;
height:200px;
position:relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
#col1,#col2,#col3{
    float:none;
    position:static;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/gZ7MY/ 
Shrink the 'Result' window to see it in action ;)

Comment: I have to disagree with you regarding the code being a mess. There is only 2 unused containers that were part of a tutorial that I have not YET removed, however they have no rules applied.

Comment: Also, My HTML is identical to the example you provided. Col1 being my center column content followed by the left column (Your col2), then the right col(your col3).

Comment: If your HTML were identical, the columns would be in the order you wanted them. I copied and pasted your code into jsfiddle to try and move things around for you but the way you had things set up didn't allow for it to be how you wanted it. Take a look at the fiddle. If you need any more help I will gladly be of your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why you have so many wrappers but moving your containers around will get you what you want. NavColumn, then ContentColumn, then ExtraColumn.

```
<div id="PageWrapper">
    <div id="Header">
        <div class="Liner">Header Links Etc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="OuterBG threecol">
        <div class="MidBG">
            <div class="InnerBG">                    
                <div id="NavColumn">
                    <div class="Liner">
                        <div class="Navigation">Site Navigation Links</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ContentColumn">
                    <div class="Liner">
                         <h1>Page Headline</h1>Page Content, Images Lorem Upsim etc...</div>
                    </div>
                <div id="ExtraColumn">
                    <div class="Liner">Extra Column Content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">Footer Content, Address etc...</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rWtDa/

Comment: @bmasteron, I know, I know... There's a lot of excess containers. These are remenants from a tutorial I was following and I do plan on removing all the excess once I have the problem sorted. Unfortunately I have to respectfully disagree with your "method" of fixing this by rearranging the content. Everyone knows content comes first for SEO reasons. When viewing site, please navigate to main site (which is "Fixed" yet displays properly)and view source

Comment: That's how float works. It respects order of elements. There is no other way to do what you are trying to do if you are going to use floats. Also SEO is a lot more complex than simply placing a div before another div.

Comment: Sorry @Bmasteron in reference to: "There is no other way to do what you are trying to do" I have to disagree. See Mr Lister's post above

Comment: Except if you inspect the elements they are interacting an unusual way. That works but its far from clean and could easily cause problems down the road with other elements around it.

Comment: One last thing. Regarding SEO, the place in the HTML your content is found is far less important than other things; proper use of head tags for example. Crawlers largely ignore things that used to be standard SEO practice, because people abused them.