# HTML/CSS float: left; is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently reading Headfirst CSS/HTML and I'm having an issue with an example.

I'm attempting to float the body to the left of the sidebar using float:left; however it's not floating properly. I've been over the HTML and CSS an I can't quite see what's wrong.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Taubin/7Lhz4wtd/

```css
#main {
  background: #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) top left;
  font-size:  105%;
  padding:    15px;
  margin:     0px 10px 10px 10px;
  width:      420px;
  float:      left;
}
```

```html
<div id="allcontent">
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p class="beanheading">
      Sidebar text
    </p>
    <p>
      Sidebar text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>QUALITY COFFEE, QUALITY CAFFEINE</h1>
    <p>
      Main text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a width to the sidebar content

Comment: @Taubin I'm on my phone right now so I can't check the jsfiddle at the moment. If somebody hasn't found a solution yet, I'll check it out for you once I'm on my pc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] reproducing the issue. The code ***in your question*** must be ***Minimal*** (only the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing more), ***Complete*** (all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing less) and ***Verifiable*** (we must be able to reproduce the issue using only the code ***in your question***, nothing more and nothing less). The code ***in your question*** must be ***the smallest program necessary to reproduce the issue***. Because of link-rot, links are not taken into account when judging a posts merit.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem JSFiddle links do not count as an MCVE because of potential link-rot. Debugging style questions require an MCVE in the question to be on-topic.

Comment: Even with the jsfiddle link excluded, the question looks sufficient enough to debug with though. This is actually an ok question for someone who just joined SO

Comment: The question still does not contain a clear problem statement or question statement. "Not floating properly" is not a clear problem statement and there is no actual question asked. @Andrew

Comment: If anything, this question is a duplicate of [this other question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287265/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant I do apologize, I searched quite a bit before posting. If this should be removed let me know and I'll remove it. I'm new to StackOverflow and am obviously not doing a lot of things correctly. Sorry for being such a bother.

Comment: @Taubin: No, you should take the [tour], read [ask] and [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then [edit] your question to fit within the guidelines. As I said before, if you include a clear problem statement and an actual question statement, your question would be fine (though as I said, it is probably a duplicate which, in itself, is not a bad thing but if true will cause closure of the question, but will not cause deletion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it might be the issue that you are adding margin and paddings, which add size to the box even though the box has a width of 420px, you have to calculate margins and paddings to, or use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`, which will calculate the width of that element as a sum of all the sizes (padding, margin, width) and not exceed the width.

Second, the order of the elements are important when floating, put main always on top of the sidebar, since elements start as top to bottom, when you float a top element, the bottom element if its wider, will collapse and align with the main box.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I had forgotten to move the sidebar to below the main. That seems to have fixed it. I think the changing of the margins and paddings comes later in the book, the finished product looks a lot more complex than the current state. I'll make a mental note of the element order being important, I had read that earlier and it didn't stick.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :), keep in mind, everyone was a beginner at the start of everything, so keep going and work hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/bg2v0dqn/.

You shouldn't add a large gap with margin.

Here's what I changed:

```css
#main {
  background:       #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) top left;
  font-size:        105%;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           0px 10px 10px 10px;
  width:            420px;
  float:            left;
}

#sidebar {
  background:       #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) bottom right;
  font-size:        105%;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           0px 10px 10px 0;
    width: 290px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#sidebar {
    background:  #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) bottom right;
    font-size:  105%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 290px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code

```css
body { 
  background-color: #b5a789;
  font-family:      Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size:        small;
  margin:           0px;
    display: table;
}

#header {
  background-color: #675c47;
  margin:           10px;
  height:           108px;
}

#main {
  background:       #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) top left;
  font-size:        105%;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           0px 10px 10px 10px;
  width:            420px;
    display: table-cell;
}

#sidebar {
  background:       #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) bottom right;
  font-size:        105%;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           0px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
    float: right;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #675c47;
  color:            #efe5d0;
  text-align:       center;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           10px;
  font-size:        90%;
  clear:            left;
}

h1 {
  font-size:        120%;
  color:            #954b4b;
}

.slogan { color: #954b4b; }

.beanheading {
  text-align:       center;
  line-height:      1.8em;
}

a:link {
  color:            #b76666;
  text-decoration:  none;
  border-bottom:    thin dotted #b76666;
}
a:visited {
  color:            #675c47;
  text-decoration:  none;
  border-bottom:    thin dotted #675c47;
}

#allcontent {
  width: 800px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #675c47;
}
```