# Position absolute bottom: Do not change flow of text

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to make element absolutely positioned to bottom in its relative parent, and retain the flow of its text content from top to bottom?

This is roughly the layout I am talking about ---

```
<div class="relative" style="padding-bottom: 2em;">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">Bottom! Can I have normal text flow, plz?</div>
    <div style="height: 10em;"></div>
</div>
```

--- and here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x507Ljyh/

Also I am opened to any creative solutions, such as pseudoelements etc. Just no changes to orders of elements in markup, please.

Thank you!

### Edit

I know, that elements with `absolute` position "do not take up space" and that's ok - the gray `article` element has generous `padding-bottom` because of that.

I just need the `h1` element text to flow from top to bottom, as would normal element do. So the scary long title "The Idler Wheel Is Wiser Than the Driver of the Screw and Whipping Cords Will Serve You More Than Ropes Will Ever Do" would end up at the bottom end of gray `article` element (and, sometimes, overflow it to bottom).

This would be similar question for floats: [HTML float right element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287265/html-float-right-element-order)

Does that make sense?

### Edit 2

Flexbox solves my issue, thanks @RoToRa! However I am still interested if flow of text content of `absolute` elements can be reversed to normal somehow, so I am leaving the question opened.

Comment: As the order of your elements currently stands in the fiddle it's actually not possible to create a clean fix, the order of the elements has to be changed so that the absolute `h1` can be a relative `h1` with some offset positioning. The best solution you could go with is to use @Jamie Clark's answer but as he mentioned it is not dynamic and will not look good / scale based on the size of the text.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: See edit of my question, please!

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine only supporting newest browsers you could use flexbox layout, and change the order of the elements:

```
article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

article > h1 {
    order: 2;
}

article > blockquote {
    order: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8pqs49qf/

Comment: Awesome! I still have not checked out flexbox properly, I had no idea it could change order of elements. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Once you make an element "position: absolute;" its space is no longer taken into consideration when the page is generated. That is why your paragraph text and header text overlap. The best way to avoid this is to add padding to the bottom of your blockquote element to make the article large enough to accommodate the space the header requires.

```
blockquote {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

The issue with this solution is it isn't very dynamic if you have multiple headers of different sizes.