# Why does floating of my example not work

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question and I do not understand why this is not working:

HTML PART:

```
<div class="main">
<p>
  KSDfao oasdkfo posfk  ojsf a osjdf klksj f lkjsdf lkjas j lsajf lkjf  jasfd
  lksf dfj ksfpwo ksdas dflkj jf kasjf ajsfl kasjdfkjasf 9j4k lsidjf  ijsf
  öskjdf jsd falksdjf öaslkjfinkasdn ig sadf sadf sadf sadf asd fas dfsd as  
  fasd fasd fasd fasd fasd fs fsdf asdfsadf sd fsad fsad fasd fasd fasd fasdf
  sdf as f
</p>
<div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS PART

```
.main{
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
}

.right{
    poition: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Text should float around the div. What is the problem here?

Comment: For starters you have a typo on your `position` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML float right element order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287265/html-float-right-element-order)

Answer (score 2):

Is this the layout you were going for? If so, remove the `position: absolute`, and put your `right` div before your text in your markup.

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <p>
    KSDfao oasdkfo posfk ojsf a osjdf klksj f lkjsdf lkjas j lsajf lkjf jasfd lksf dfj ksfpwo ksdas dflkj jf kasjf ajsfl kasjdfkjasf 9j4k lsidjf ijsf öskjdf jsd falksdjf öaslkjfinkasdn ig sadf sadf sadf sadf asd fas dfsd as fasd fasd fasd fasd fasd fs fsdf
    asdfsadf sd fsad fsad fasd fasd fasd fasdf sdf as f
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @GeorgKiedl Glad to be able to help! Do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!