# why is this button to the right of this other button, why not to the left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

In this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fitiha/10/edit?js,output

Why is the "Tweet button" to the right of the "Add Photo" button. Per the code below, I believe it should be to the left?

```
    <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right"
      disabled={this.state.text.length === 0 && !this.state.photoAdded}>Tweet
    </button>
    <button className="btn btn-default pull-right"
      onClick={this.togglePhoto}>
      {this.state.photoAdded ? "✓ Photo Added" : "Add Photo" }
    </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `pull-right` class which is essentially `float:right` and that's how it works.

It stacks the elements in inverted order of their occurence.

Since, Tweet occured before Add Photo, it got floated to the right, and then add photo followed.

You could read up the CSS Spec here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287265/html-float-right-element-order) SO answer for more info on how float works.

Comment: Actually, it stacks elements in the order they are found in the document but since it stacks right to left they end up looking visually inverted.