# li items list in reverse

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This is my portfolio: http://nayer.42web.io/
I have used HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. There is a problem with my li elements which I can't figure out. They all list in reverse, both header and footer. For example, I have my header as:

```
<header id="header">
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li id="brand" style="float:left; font-family:'Dancing Script', sans-serif;font-weight:800;font-size:1.5rem"><a href="index.php">Nira</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#logos">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

But on my page, it gets listed in the following order: Nayer About Contact Projects.
Of course, I can list them in reverse myself so when it gets reversed it shows in the right order, but I wonder what my code's issue is.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this on your css:

```
nav li {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1.3em;
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The float right sets your first item to the far right position, then the second items on it left and so on ... which reverses the order. Then you have a float left for your "Nira" item that sets it to the far left.

You can refer to this for more details: [HTML float right element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287265/html-float-right-element-order)

Comment: I didn't know that about float, thank you. Do you know how I can achieve the result I want?

Comment: You can use the navbar-right class attribute on your ul as you're using bootstrap

Comment: You can separate the navbar into 2 different ``<ul>`` and set the float on those (the parents).